# Export to shapefile error in QGIS from POSTGIS table

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile, export

I am attempting to export a postGIS layer to a shapefile in QGIS 2.6.1 Brighton. The table has 244,674 rows. The data displays perfectly well in QGIS but when I attempt to export to shapefile I get this error:

> Feature geometry not imported (OGR error: Value 1027563200 of field aland of feature 35053 >not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger number with respect to field width)

I went to the listed feature but the aland column isn't the value listed in the error. What am I missing here? Do I need to change my column settings?

Comment: Maybe try export to File Geodatabase.  If that works, maybe you are hitting a limitation with dBASE (e.g. field names > 10 characters, field string value > 255 characters ...etc).

Comment: After much wrestling I remembered that PostGIS shapefile importer also has an exporter option. So, I left QGIS and just exported the table as a shapefile through PostGIS. I am still not sure what the issue was with QGIS.